# Synchronise Decoded Audio and Video data from Mediacodec

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to write a simple audio/video player using the `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec` APIs.

I am able to decode and render the `audio` and `video`.
But, I am missing the `audio - video` sync.

I couldn't find any API to control sync between `audio` and `video`.
Can somebody please tell me, how to synchronise the decoded `audio` and `video` data ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Android sources, there is an example `player` engine implementation based on `MediaCodec` APIs. You could check for `SimplePlayer` located at [`frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp).

In this player engine implementation, the output from the `MediaCodec` is `dequeued` and pushed into a queue as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#450). Please check lines 439 - 450 to get a complete picture.

Once the buffer is available, there is a simple `AV Sync` mechanism implemented [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#508). Please refer to lines 508 -521. In this example, only one track is considered and hence, `nowUs` i.e. the current time is derived from `systemTime` i.e. `ALooper::nowUs`.

In your code, you can consider rendering `audio` always on `first-come-first-serve` basis and for your `video` track, you can **derive** the `nowUs` from the `audio` track.

A simple implementation could be the `nowUs = getAudioLastPresentationTime()` where, `getAudioLastPresentationTime` will return the last `presentationTimeUs` sent from the `audio` `MediaCodec` to `audio renderer`.

Comment: @ManojK.. The link http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#508 is a working sample which can be tried on an `android` platform. Please clarify if you are looking for something different.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was hoping any sample code in java. anyhow i will try above mentioned sample n keep u posted.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, you mentioned that, `In this example, only one track is considered` , could you explain this ? I suspect this considers atleast both audio and video.